# NodeJs - Async/Await inside controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have this simple example to my controller and doesn't work as expected

```
export let create = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

   console.log("START");
   await setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("MIDDLE");
   }, 1000);
   console.log("END");
   return res.json({ data: null });

};
```

Output: START,END,MIDDLE

EXPECT: START,MIDDLE,END

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: I think it is obvious.... START... MIDDLE... END

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a **number**, not a promise. Only if you `await` a promise does the execution actually "wait".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `setTimeOut` without creating the promise object, so it's waiting for the `setTimeOut` value to be returned (which is instant) rather than waiting for a promise resolution. This is the reason your `await` statement isn't working the way it was intended to. What you need is to create a promise:

```
function resolveAfterOneSecond(x) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Middle");
      resolve(x);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfterOneSecond(10);
  console.log("End");
}

console.log("Begin");
f1();
```

and then set your function to await the return of the promise, rather than the return of the setTimeOut function integer.